# page is scrolling down when i use next tab button in tab menu

Tags: jquery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        $(".nexttab").click(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs("select", this.hash);
        });
    });

</script>


<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">  <a class="nexttab" href="#tabs-1">  << Back  </a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class="nexttab" href="#tabs-3">Next >> </a> </td>
</tr>
```

When i use above code it is perfectly moving to next tab and previous tab. but problem is when i go to next or previous tab, my screen is going down ( i mean page is scrolling down little but). could you Please help me out.. Thanks in advance.

Regards
Ramesh

Answer (score 1):

The `#tabs-1` and `#tabs-3` in your anchor tags is making the browser to jump to these anchor points. To prevent this, add `return false;` to the end of your click handler, to prevent the default browser action.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `return false` in your `click` handler, so it do not jump to the defined hash.

```
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs("select", this.hash);
  return false;
});
```

Also using `<< Back` or `Next >>` is not valid. Use `&lt;&lt; Back` instead or even `Next &gt;&gt;`